# how does a create-react app work without an index.html?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react app (that I think is based of create-react-app - I didn't create it initially)

Doesn't use an index.html, it has an index.js, well it has a few index.js,

I want to know how this works? Basically when I run npm run build, a build folder isnt created, an es and a lib folder are created which are copies of the src folder (which contains the components)

Why are these two folders created and not a build?

I used an npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chat-window

Here is my package.json (might hold the clues):

I really want to understand because on my server, I am using nginx, but it isnt routed to any of the files, the sites-available/default doesnt route to anywhere its the default settings so how does it work!?

```
{
  "name": "react-chat-window",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "description": "react-live-chat React component",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "module": "es/index.js",
  "files": [
    "css",
    "es",
    "lib",
    "umd"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nwb build-react-component --copy-files",
    "clean": "nwb clean-module && nwb clean-demo",
    "start": " nwb serve-react-demo",
    "gh:publish": "nwb build-demo && gh-pages -d demo/dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.2.0",
    "emoji-js": "3.2.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "15.5.10",
    "react-highlight.js": "1.0.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "socket.io-client": "2.0.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nwb": "0.17.x",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/kingofthestack/react-live-chat.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react-component"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I've not used github pages myself but perhaps this holds the clue?  As I can see gh-pages is in your package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not using create-react-app , you're using another boilerplate called nwb , here is his official documentation to understand how it works https://github.com/insin/nwb  and here is his documentation concerning react 
https://github.com/insin/nwb/blob/master/docs/guides/ReactApps.md#developing-react-apps-with-nwb

Comment: I think that was my problem I've been looking at create-react-app solutions! Thank you.